# ios Ad-hoc install won't complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an iOS app that I want to test by doing an ad-hoc install through iTunes instead of through Xcode to make sure that it meets Apples guidelines. (It had a crash on the iPad when I submitted it the first time. I think I fixed it, but I want to test it this way to make sure)

It installed the first time, when I was verifying that I got the same crash that Apple got. When I fixed the bug and re-archived/exported the ipa file, imported it into iTunes and copied it to the iPad it started to install and then failed part way.

The app showed up on the screen, the install status circle appeared and started to fill, and then it just stopped, the circle went away, and now the icon is sitting there greyed out. According to iTunes it's still installing.

Not sure what to do with it now to finish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have a provisioning profile problem.
You need to make sure that your device (whatever the device you are using) has it's UUID first of all in the iOS Member Center, and secondly in the actual provisioning profile you are using for the Ad Hoc build.

Comment: That appears to have been the problem... Why would it have let me put it on there the first time? If it's gonna fail, it should fail the first time instead of making me think that everything is ok.